# Как запустить потоки поочередно?

Tags: c#, многопоточность

Разбираюсь с потоками, и никак не могу понять. Как запустить поток который будет идти после окончания второго?
Делал и с приоритетностю, и с Join() даже что-то пытался(но не понял его принцип). Но все равно работает не так как я хочу. В итоге, понял что это должно делаться с lock-оператором. Но все равно не получается...

```
class Print {
    public void Display() {
        lock (this) {
            for (int counter = 0; counter < 5; counter++) {
                Console.WriteLine("{0} -> {1}", this.GetType(), counter);
                Thread.Sleep(200);
            }
        }
    }
}

class Program {
    static void Main() {
        Print print = new Print();

        Thread primaryThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(print.Display));
        primaryThread.Name = "Thread #1";
        primaryThread.Start();

        Thread secondaryThread = new Thread(RunSecondThread);
        secondaryThread.Start();

    }
 }
```

Вообще задача такая, сделать 3 потока. Где 2й запускает 3й поток в фоне, а 1й потом запускается после завершения 2.

```
 class Program {
    static void Main() {
        Thread primaryThread = Thread.CurrentThread;
        primaryThread.Name = "Thread #1";


        Thread secondaryThread = new Thread(RunSecondThread);
        secondaryThread.Start();

        primaryThread.Priority = ThreadPriority.Lowest;
        secondaryThread.Priority = ThreadPriority.Highest;

        for (int counter = 0; counter < 5; counter++) {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} -> {1}", primaryThread.Name, counter);
            Thread.Sleep(200);
        }
    }

    static void RunSecondThread() {
        Thread secondaryThread = Thread.CurrentThread;
        secondaryThread.Name = "Thread #2";

        Thread thirdThread = new Thread(RunThirdThread);
        thirdThread.IsBackground = true;
        thirdThread.Start();

        for (int counter = 0; counter < 5; counter++) {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} -> {1}", secondaryThread.Name, counter);
            Thread.Sleep(500);
        }
    }

    static void RunThirdThread() {
        Thread thirdThread = Thread.CurrentThread;
        thirdThread.Name = "Thread #3";

        for (int counter = 0; counter < 5; counter++) {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} -> {1}", thirdThread.Name, counter);
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот так это должно работать

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Thread primaryThread = Thread.CurrentThread;
        primaryThread.Name = "Thread #1";
        primaryThread.Priority = ThreadPriority.Lowest;
        
        Thread secondaryThread = new Thread(RunSecondThread);
        secondaryThread.Priority = ThreadPriority.Highest;
        secondaryThread.Start();
        secondaryThread.Join();//дождатся выполнения 

        //потом будет работать этот цикл 
        for (int counter = 0; counter < 5; counter++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} -> {1}", primaryThread.Name, counter);
            Thread.Sleep(200);
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

на выходе получаем такой результат
Основной поток(#1) продолжает свою работу после того как поток(#2)завершился

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]